# Are there problem sets for trace table problems? If not, what are some good topics to cover?

Tags: pseudo-code, problem-structure

A trace table problem is code that you follow along by hand and fill out variable values at each line. For example.

```py
0  msg = 'hello'
1  num = 5
2  num = num + 1
3  if num < 6:
4      msg = 'goodbye'
5  print(msg)
```

The table is filled out with variable values at each line number.

```
line | num | msg     | 
0    |     | 'hello' |
1    | 5   | 'hello' |
2    | 6   | 'hello' |
3    | 6   | 'hello' |
4    |     |         |
5    | 6   | 'hello' |
```

This would be for a collection of beginner language problems, to provide practice and review understanding of programming language operations. These are the CS 101 style problems of what does this print, or what is x at the end of this. An initial topic list might be as follows.

- variable declaration
- function declaration
- function calls
- if / else if / else
- for / while
- arithmetic
- scope
- asynchronous

Are there any resources or existing collections for these types of problems? Specifically looking for Javascript but I can adapt other problems to the language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such resources, and I expect that there wouldn't be. These are great problems, but you (hopefully) only need to do a few of them until the concepts click into place.

I didn't know these were called trace table problems, but I have often provided them to struggling students in three different contexts:

1. **Absolute beginners**, where it helps students understand the ideas of assignment and execution order
2. **Strugglers**, where it helps students understand whatever has them lost, and
3. **Students working on very low-level problems**, such as assembly, or on processor design.  Here it is more of a basic survival tool. There are few, if any, meaningful variable names, and working your way through the values is a straightforward way of figuring out what is going on.

And this gets me to why I don't think you'll find a specific resource for problems like these: in all three of these scenarios, the actual prompt is the specific code we're studying.  Tracing the values is just a tool to understand the code that is in front of you.  The value-add (and the overarching purpose) comes from that code, not from the trace table per se.